# Get Page Access Token from FQL?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

I'm having difficulty finding a way to get a page access_token from FQL.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts
- This is the graph call with the page access_tokens included.  The trouble is that I need the access tokens for a multiquery call and would love to not have to make a separate call just for the access tokens then call the same info for my multiquery.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/
- This doesn't contain the access token, although it mentions contains the same data as the /user/accounts graph api call.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/
- This also doesn't seem to include the page access token.

Has anyone had luck or found a way to get that token through FQL?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible!

`SELECT access_token FROM page WHERE page_id={id}`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the access token from FQL, you can only do it via Graph API calls.

FQL is for queries from tables.

Graph API is for GET, POST and DELETE requests